# How to render pseudo before content dynamically in styled-component

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm having a trouble of rendering pseudo before content dynamically in styled-components.

Am I doing something wrong?

I have no problem when I render pseudo before content statically, but it doesn't work when I try it dynamically.

## React Component

```
const Test = (props) => {

    return (
        <Text before={12345}>
            {props.children}
        </Text>
    );

};
```

## Styled Component(Not Work)

```
const Text = styled.span`

    &:before {
        content: ${props => {
            console.log(props.before); // I see '12345' in log.
            return props.before;
            }
    }


`;
```

## Styled Component(This works fine)

```
const Text = styled.span`

    &:before {
        content: '12345'
    }


`;
```

Comment: It's not recommended to use dynamic content property with styled components as it will create new class for each content, if there are only a few different 'contents' you're fine, but if it can be anything you may have bad performance.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

That is because `content` value must be within quotes in css

Example:

```
const Block = styled.div`
    &:before {
        position: absolute;
        top:0;
        content: '${props => props.before}'
    }
`
```

Please note that I am leveraging [ES6 new features](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/es6-functions-9f61c72b1e86#5ef8) wherein a single statement function there is no need to use curly braces `{}` and `return`.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/metju/pen/zEKeOm

Comment: Why do you have to wrap the expression in another quote, even if you are already returning a string? e.g.  `content: ${props => props.test ? "foo" : " bar"};` fails `content: '${props => props.test ? "foo" : " bar"}';` works

Comment: Slight typo:

`position: absolute`

not

`display: absolute`

Comment: Thanks for spotting that 5+ years old typo, @Zylvian!

Comment: @MatthewBarbara The beauty of the internet.

Answer (score 3):

What I did is use the css helper function for this:

```
const Text = styled.span`
  &:before {
     ${props => !!props.before ?
      css`content: props.before;` : css`content: ' '';`
     };
  }
`
```

Answer (score 1):

styled-components works the same as in sass, nothing different

```
const Text = styled.span`
    &:before {
       content: ${props => !!props.before ? props.before : " "};
    }
```

`;

I am a // renders: "I am a "

Reference taken from 
[Before and After pseudo classes used with styled-components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45871439/before-and-after-pseudo-classes-used-with-styled-components)

Comment: I have used ```!!props.before```, this is a truthy statement which converts a string into a Boolean. Just to check if you are getting ```props.before``` or not.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But, it doesn't work... I tried this as well.   
&:before {
    content: ${props => !!props.before ? 'aaa' : "bbb"};
  } Both 'aaa' and 'bbb' doesn"t get rendered.

Comment: Of course, as I mentioned in my post, If I write like this, it works. 
 &:before {
        content: '12345'
    }