# React styled-components ::before and ::after pseudo elements not showing when passing functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I want to add `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements to a `css` style-object from styled-components, such that I can reuse them in multiple other style elements (I am doing it for `AboutWrapper` in the example code). However, the `::after` does not show up, when I run the code. The `::before` is showing. It is the other way around, when I switch their positions in the code. I noticed, that both pseudo elements show up, when I comment out the functions that set `top`, `left` and `bottom` and replace them with constant values. What is the problem?

Unfortunately, the code snippet here on Stackoverflow is not runnable and I am not sure why... maybe I need to include styled-components somehow?

```js
import React from 'react'
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components'


export const showHtmlTagStyle = css`
    position: relative;     // important for the before and after

  &::before {
    content: '<section>';
    font-family: 'La Belle Aurore', cursive;
    color: #fff; 
    font-size: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    top: ${(props) => (props.tagTop ? props.tagTop : '1rem') };//1rem;
    left: ${(props) => (props.tagLeft ? props.tagLeft : '2rem')};//2rem;
  }

  &::after {
    content: '/section';
    font-family: 'La Belle Aurore', cursive;
    color: #fff; 
    font-size: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: ${(props) => (props.tagBottom ? props.tagBottom : '1rem') };//1rem;
    left: ${(props) => (props.tagLeft ? props.tagLeft : '2rem')};//2rem;
  }
`

export const AboutWrapper = styled.div`
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    ${showHtmlTagStyle}
`

const AboutSection = () => {
  return (
    <AboutWrapper tagTop='1rem' tagLeft='2rem'>
      Just some random Text that should have a 'before' tag before it and an 'after' tag after it.
    </AboutWrapper>
  )
}


ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <AboutSection />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using just 1 `:` instead of 2 (`::`) as described inside [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45871869/19330762)

```
export const showHtmlTagStyle = css`
    position: relative;     // important for the before and after

  &:before {
    content: '<section>';
    font-family: 'La Belle Aurore', cursive;
    color: #fff; 
    font-size: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    top: ${(props) => (props.tagTop ? props.tagTop : '1rem') };//1rem;
    left: ${(props) => (props.tagLeft ? props.tagLeft : '2rem')};//2rem;
  }

  &:after {
    content: '/section';
    font-family: 'La Belle Aurore', cursive;
    color: #fff; 
    font-size: 18px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: ${(props) => (props.tagBottom ? props.tagBottom : '1rem') };//1rem;
    left: ${(props) => (props.tagLeft ? props.tagLeft : '2rem')};//2rem;
  }
`
```

Comment: I tried that, but this is not the solution unfortunately